# Creating array names

Tags: c#

I have the following code, for example:

```
int[] mass_1 = new int[666];
int[] mass_2 = new int[666]; 
..... 
int[] mass_100 = new int[666];
```

Can I programatically change the names of arrays - instead mass_1, mass_2.....mass_100 - something like:

```
int X = 1;  
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) 
{
   string Y = X.ToString()); 
   int[] mass_Y = new int[666]; 
   X++;
}
```

It's clear - a code don't work. Any ideas how to create 100 (or more) arrays with creating names programmatically? Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `int[100,666]`? Because in its current state, I can't understand this post.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you would like to create variable variable names?  Can you use an hash array instead with a keyname equal to your mass name?

Comment: Even if this was php or other dynamic language doing this would not be advisable. You've got several options here. Three comes in my mind right now: 1. create 2 dimensional array (this will have better performance over my second and third solutions). 2. create a list of arrays. This will give you flexibility to add/remove items. 3. use `Dictionary<K,V>` instead of `List<T>` if you want to manually set keys.

Comment: It really depends on what's your purpose here. Can you give an example where those are not `mass` but have actual names you are using?

Comment: Thanks to all- maybe 2 dimensional - more simple for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can't crate source code that will allow you to dynamically change the names, at compile time but you can associate variables with names at runtime.
Create a dictionary to put your arrays into. This will allow you to store each array with a string name.

Answer (score 0):

2-dimensional array:

```
int[100,666] mass = new int[100,666];
```